# I have searched but could not find the one unique and proper method

Tags: ios6

I have a registration form in which i have used around 7 textfields. But when i starts to enter the values in that the keyboard hides the lower 3 fields.I want to move up my view but not by using scroll view.Please tell me any solution for that.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Register for Keyboard Show and Hide Notification.

```
- (void)registerForKeyboardNotifications {
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWasShown:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification object:nil];

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(keyboardWillBeHidden:)
                                                 name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification object:nil];
}
```

--

Now in the `- (void)keyboardWasShown:(NSNotification*)iNotification` method, get the Keyboard Size using

```
     NSDictionary *anUserInfo = [iNotification userInfo];
     CGSize aKeyboardSize = [[anUserInfo objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

Based on the device being iPhone 5 or iPhone 4, get the size of screen too.

Now you will be in a position to figure out the hidden fields and distance the view has to slide up to make the hidden fields visible.

Use `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField` delegate of the TextField. Everytime, a hidden textfield is about to be edited, calculate the distance it should move up to be visible.

Once you get the distance, animate the view to move up.

How to move up:

```
    CGFloat aDistanceToMakeFieldVisible = 50.0; //you have to calculate this
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{
        CGRect aFrame = self.view.frame;
        aFrame.origin.y -= aDistanceToMakeFieldVisible;
        self.view.frame = aFrame;
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    }];
```

---

Dont forget to Animate Down too...

Comment: i know this is stupid que. but i m new in ios will u plz tell me that how to use - (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField method how to animate down also

Comment: To Animate Down, you should use `- (BOOL)textFieldShouldEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField` delegate method.

Comment: i uses this method but there is no effect.Plz post a whole code from start to end may be there would be any mistake in my code.